# Multi tenant MVC4 application and automatic DB migrations with Entity Framework - Good practice?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-migrations

I've built a multi tenant MVC4 application that use a specific database depending on the hostname.

The site binds to all of our customers hostnames:

- If a visitor surfs to 'domain1.com', the 'domain1.com' database is used.
- If a visitor surfs to 'domain2.com, the 'domain2.com' database is used.

Automatic migrations are normally placed in Application_Start():

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyProject.Models.MyProjectContext, MyProject.Migrations.Configuration>());
```

This will run the migrations on application start. However, since my application responds to several hostnames, only one database will be migrated. When i switch to another hostname, that database IS NOT migrated since the application is already loaded into memory on the server.

I solved this by moving the above line of code to Session_Start().

Is this good practice? Is there a better solution?

Thanks in advance,

Andreas

Comment: hi, any solution? I have this problem too :(